# Getting PDF data to SQL Server? Example in description

Tags: asp.net, sql, itext, pdf-form

I am in the process of making something similar to this:

http://www.artversion.com/pdf/WebsiteDesignQuestionnaires.pdf

I have a questionnaire, I was planning to use a pdf to get the answers and put the data into database. I have looked at itextsharp and pdfSharp, however, the questionnaire are fairly lengthy like the one above. So my question is, how or where should I start with something like this? Or if there is a better way to doing this, without using pdf's?

This will be made using ASP.NET and SQL.

Thanks in advance.

I apologize if my editing is not proper, I'm fairly new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: "Or if there is a better way to doing this, without using pdf's?" What are your requirements? PDF has strengths and weaknesses. There are many ways to connect a web form with a database: you need to determine your requirements (and skillset should figure into that) to select the best option.

Comment: The requirements are, the questionnaire is to review a 'potential candidates'. I need to store the answers from a reviewer(multiple reviewers) in a database where I use them later to make a cumulative report of said 'potential candidate'. I wanted to use a pdf simply because I could store a copy of the questionnaire in readable text format.

Comment: I'm fairly new to .NET, and I'm more of a front-end kind of guy, but I've recently started with back-end development. That being said, I am not hesitant to learn.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid using PDFs for this purpose all together and stick with a standard ASP.NET page or Silverlight if you're looking for a richer UI.

Comment: @NickHeidke That was my initial thought. I just thought that it would be more efficient and cleaner to use PDF's as the middle man.

Comment: +1 @NickHeidke PDFs are good when you need to emulate pages of paper. PDFs are good for presentation, but not flexible for a web interface. A key thing you haven't mentioned: will users have a web connection when completing the form or might they be offline? If offline, the case for PDF becomes a little stronger. Otherwise, sounds like they won't be worth the trouble.

Comment: I generally treat PDFs as an output tool rather than an input tool. I gather the input using standard web techs, then if you're users are looking for a specific print friendly output, PDFs might be just the ticket.

Comment: Thanks @NickHeidke, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I used the PDF as an output tool and used regular web forms for input.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer if you want to mark it as such. Glad to hear you got your problem solved!

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't, so I've added an answer below with my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using PDFs for this purpose all together and stick with a standard ASP.NET page or Silverlight if you're looking for a richer UI. Treat PDFs as an output tool rather than an input tool. Gather the input using standard web techs, then if you're users are looking for a specific print friendly output, PDFs might be just the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to read and write PDF forms with iTextSharp. 
Here are some samples:

- [Collecting Data Directly from PDF](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_button_fields.aspx)
- [Filling and processing Adobe PDF Forms with iTextSharp](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/10/filling-and-processing-adobe-pdf-forms.html)
- [Fill in PDF Form Fields using the Open Source iTextSharp Dynamic Link Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23112/Fill-in-PDF-Form-Fields-using-the-Open-Source-iTex)
- [Filling in PDF Forms with ASP.NET and iTextSharp](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030211-1.aspx)